# Infinite redirect in Symfony

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, redirect

I'm setting up a test environment for our Symfony web site. I have a basic version working on my Windows machine for development, but trying to set up an AWS replica of the production web site as test causes all the valid pages to end up in an infinite 301 redirect. I'm guessing I've missed something in the configuration.

- Symfony 2.8
- AWS Ubuntu server
- SSL enabled, and non-Symfony files served correctly

This is the raw response header for `/app/dashboard`:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 06 Nov 2017 05:43:18 GMT
Location: https://****.***/app/dashboard
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22
Content-Length: 424
Connection: keep-alive
```

The Apache, PHP and Symfony `/app/config/parameters.yml` configurations are identical to the Production and Dev environments, except for server addresses. Composer has been run to download all the project dependencies.

Production and Dev both work fine. It's only Test that has the infinite redirect loops.

I'm sure there's something simple I've overlooked but I can't find it.

#### UPDATE 8 Nov 2017

`/app_dev.php` works, but `/app.php` has the infinite loop.

- GET /app.php (**https**)

  - Location: http://****.***/
- GET / (http)

  - Location: http://****.***/app/dashboard
- GET /app/dashboard (http)

  - Location: **https**://****.***/app/dashboard
- GET /app/dashboard (**https**)

  - Location: **https**://****.***/app/dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem went away "by itself". I had tried a few things to debug it that didn't work, so I used `rsync` to reset all the files back to a pristine state, at which point the problem stopped happening.

#### UPDATE

I managed to break it again somehow. I then remembered I'd changed the `trusted_proxies` in the configuration, and that got overwritten when I `rsync`'d it. Adding the correct settings back in fixed the problem!

```
framework:
    ...
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies:  [<correct settings go in here>]
    ...
```